# Incresing API request concurrency using PHP

Tags: php, apache, api, ubuntu, nginx

I've developed an application using PHP to accept api requests. I've used `Apache Benchmark` to check the max concurrent request it can handle per second from another remote server. I've used concurrency to max 200 with a request load of max 10,000. The best request it can handle is 139 requests per seconds. I want to increase it. How can I do so?

**My server configuration is**

```
Intel Xeon E3-1230v6 - 4 c / 8 t - 3.5 GHz / 3.9 GHz
RAM: 32GB
Storage: SSD 480GB x 2 (in RAID-1 soft raid)
Network bandwidth: 500Mbps

OS: Ubuntu 18
Server Management: Plesk Web Pro (Apache-Nginx)
PHP Version: 7.3
Database: MariaDB 10.1.44
Database max allowed concurrent connection: 2000
My server Ping Time from test server 200ms.
```

My script max processing time is 0.04~0.06 second.

I've tried with NodeJS, interestingly instead of increasing, it decreases the request level to 15 requests per seconds.

I've used Redis Cache (hosted with Docker), and yet no luck. Level is same as 138~139.

I really need to set it in between 500~1000. How can I achieve this?

I've no modification on OS level. All are set as default.

Thanks in Advance for reading this.

Comment: I could try that right now

Comment: PHP Version: 7.3 I mentioned it in the Server details. Letting you know the update as soon as I test.

Comment: If redis didn't help, then your bottleneck is likely apache/nginx. Also, are you trying to serve 500-1000 requesta per second OR are you trying to get per server performance to 500-1000 per second?

Comment: @NicholasSummers 
I was just checking the PHP version and interestingly I saw, I was running my server with FPM with Apache, not nginx. I just checked it from FPM with Apache to FPM with Nginx, and for redis, the request level gets to 300+ (310~312). But if I use Mysql, then it does not changes. And right now I only have one server, so I've to get it within this server. I am trying to serve 500-1000 requesta per second.

Comment: The point I am making is that if you are trying to handle more than 50-100 requests per second, it is a much more stable and easy option to deploy multiple PHP servers, and load balance between them. The most I have ever gotten out of a single PHP server is about 300 requests per second with a lot of caching and it wasn't stable. That was several years ago so you can probably get more, but 500-1000 may not be reasonably possible.

Comment: Redis can handle about 500 requests per second, for every CPU thread. (At least in AWS) So redis is likely going to be the key to breaking 500. (PHP likely wont be able to get past 150-200 without it) - This is assuming your redis instance is on the same LAN as your server.

Comment: @NicholasSummers Thanks for your kind experience sharing. I was guessing so. But I just want to be sure with experts opinions like you. If there is any way! Right now its not possible for me to go to cloud and use multiple instances with load balance. I've to be with this dedicated server for at least 3~6 more months.

Comment: Some final hints: use redis to cache database queries & PHP output; cached PHP output doesn't need a high resource server; load balancers, web servers, & databases don't need to all be on the same hosting provider to work; API's are way cheaper in resources than full web-pages; AWS S3 (or simialar services) are your friend. - Good Luck!

Comment: @RazinAbid : two possible bottenecks 1) outbound calling capacity of your test server, 2) the provisioned IOPS for the MariaDB instance of the system under test.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a syncronous language that uses a interpreter to run it's scripts.
Every request coming to PHP CGI will wait for previous request to complete. PHP uses ProcessManagers (PHP-FPM/Apache mod_php) to overcome this problem. Try increasing number of active workers

Comment: How can I increase active worker in PHP? What are the settings?

Comment: I did. I set `pm` to `static` and `pm.max_children` to 200. But no change. The default value was `pm` to `ondemand` and `pm.max_children` to 10

Comment: @RazinAbid you need to restart the php service and possibly apache for the changes to take effect. Also, monitor the fpm manager with the status url normally activated, during your load test, to get a sense of the number of active processes. If it is too low, your have another blocking component in your architecture.

Comment: First, use your current active fpm pool config.

Second, try to use pm = static. Other have some overhead to startup new workers.

Third, do not overload your CPU with excessive ammount of workers.

```
[p73]
...
pm = static
pm.max_children = 24
pm.max_requests = 1000
...
```

This will start 24 workers in pending state each worker can handle no more then 1000 requests than will be restarted.

You can read more in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31411779/7534084